# Ion-segment default active but the value is data binded to firebase {{cate.id}} helpppp please

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

i am trying to display the first tab from the segment that is binded to my my firebase, i have tried doing the topbar: string = ""; ?????? but my value is undefined because is data binded i really do not have any idea what can i do to have my segment enabled by default when the user opens the page. Here is my code: `

```
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="topbar">
      <div *ngFor="let cate of categories">

      <ion-segment-button  value="{{cate.id}}" [id]="cate.id" >
        {{cate.name}}
      </ion-segment-button>

      </div>
    </ion-segment>
    
  </ion-toolbar>`
```

Here is the ts(i know its wrong :( ):

```
 topbar: string = "{{cate.id}}";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

**In html**

```
   <ion-segment scrollable value="{{firstId}}" (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)">
   
      <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let cate of categories" value="{{cate.id}}" id="{{cate.id}}" >        
        <ion-label>{{cate.name}}</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    

    </ion-segment>
```

You need to give *firstId* to first category *id* from ts file.

**In ts**

```
firstId: any;

getDataFromServer()
{
  //your code to get data

  //after add this
  this.firstId = category[0].id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked as expected!!!!! you saved my day.